# Isomorphism & Quotient Ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-writing

Consider the function $\varphi$ from $R=\{a+bi|a,b\in\mathbb{Z}\}$ to $\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ with $p=4m+1$,defined by $\varphi(a+bi)=[a+bt]p$ where $[j]p$ denotes the residue class of the integer $j \mod p$ and $t=(2m)!$. I'm asked to prove that this function is an homomorphism, that is kernel is equal to $I=(p,t+i)$ and to find what the quotient ring $R/I$ is isomorphic to.
I managed to answer the 2 first questions but I'm stucked on the last one. Can anyone help me ?
Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a great example of how to ask a question on this site, by the way. I hope other posters take note!

Answer (score 0):

There is a theorem (one of the "Isomorphism Theorems") that says that the quotient of a ring by the kernel of a homomorphism out of that ring is isomorphic to the image of that homomorphism. Using that theorem here should make it easier to identify what $R/I$ is isomorphic to.

If for some reason you're not allowed to use that theorem, you could think of the quotient in two steps. Set $J = (t+i)$, an ideal contained inside $I$. Then $R/I$ is the result of quotienting out first by $J$, then by the "rest of $I$", which is $(p)$. (Formally, $R/I \cong (R/J)/(I/J)$.) Can you identify $R/J$? (Hint: every element of $R$ can be written as a multiple of $t+i$ plus an element of $\mathbb Z$ in a unique way.)

Comment: I didn't this theorem. Thanks for your help. If I understood correctly what are quotient ring (what I'm really not sure about I have to confess), R/J should be equal to Z isn't it ? Which would lead R/I to be equal to Z/pZ. Thanks again

Comment: Right on both counts!